# Which PATH variable is valid for launchers?

Tags: environment-variables

In my `.bashrc` file I have defined PATH variable, but it seems it's not validated by desktop launchers

Where should I define PATH variable so that launchers can pick it up?

Comment: After installing lxde every icon in bin folder is included in gnome shell menu and it became ugly and useless answer of this qustion may help me too :)

Answer (score 2):

PATH variable can be defined in `~/.profile` file, instead `~/.bashrc` so that it will be available to launchers

Answer (score 1):

Follow below step to define path variable available for all launcher for manually installed JDK

Step:

1-

```
 cd /etc/
```

2-

```
sudo vim ~/.profile
```

3- Add below codes in your step2 open file

```
  PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/lib:$PATH"

  JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79"

  export JAVA_HOME

  PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

  export PATH
```

4-Restart your system

Answer (score 0):

The PATH set in `.bashrc` is only called when you open a new instance of bash (i.e. opening a `gnome-terminal`.  In the .desktop files, I believe it's best to just include the entire path to whichever program you're launching, i.e. `/usr/bin/program-to-launch`

Comment: Thanks, but I know that already. Question is where should I define PATH variable so that it works for launchers